# How to get (extract) / set TraceContext from/into tracer in spring sleuth

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I have a requirement where the complete flow of different async requests is related with one trackingId across different services which communicate asynchronously with the help of messages, And I need to have a single traceId for all requests related to one flow or trackingId.

And I am facing issues with getting/setting TraceContext from/into Tracer, I wrote below code but it creates a new traceId for each request.

```
TraceContext traceContext = (TraceContext) contextMap.get(trackingId);
if (traceContext == null)
{
    tracing.tracer().startScopedSpan(trackingId);
    traceContext = tracing.currentTraceContext().get();
} else
{
    tracing.tracer().startScopedSpanWithParent(trackingId, traceContext);
}

contextMap.put(trackingId, traceContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what do you want to achieve here, as far as I can understand, what you described is the default behavior, please see the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/3.0.0/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started-terminology).

The tracing context is propagated out of the box, so all the related spans have the same traceId, please see the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/3.0.0/reference/htmlsingle/#how-to-set-up-sleuth-with-brave-zipkin-messaging) how you can set this up for messaging, there is also a [sample project for messaging](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/tree/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-samples/spring-cloud-sleuth-sample-messaging).

Comment: I am aware of that but how you will change traceId for different trackingId and keep it the same for the same trackingId across services.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this sentence. What do you mean by trackingId? There is traceId and spanId, there's no trackingId.

Comment: It is mentioned in the question, I have a requirement where the complete flow of different async requests is related with one trackingId across different services which communicate asynchronously with the help of messages, And I need to have a single traceId for all requests related to one flow or trackingId.